# Filter function based on attribute. Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, filter, web-gis, feature-filter

Im trying to create a webmap based on [Leaflet - google spreedsheets example](https://www.datavizforall.org/leaflet/with-google-sheets/)

I have a a "group" layer with three diferent group names.

I have added some easy buttons to click the layers on and off, but I have only been able to make it work on the entire "group" layer.

My buttons:

```
var buttons = {
  Agriculture: L.easyButton({
    position: 'topright',
    states: [{
      stateName: 'add-markers',
      icon: '<img alt="do this" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/orange-agriculture-icon-png-0.png" height="40" width="40" align="left" style="opacity:0.4 "/><span id="text" class="btn--text"><font color="black"><b>Agriculturee</b></font></span>',
      title: 'add random markers',
      onClick: function(control) {
        map.addLayer(group);
        control.state('remove-markers');
      }
    }, {
      icon: '<img alt="do this" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/orange-agriculture-icon-png-0.png" height="40" width="40" align="left"/><span id="text" class="btn--text"><font color="black"><b>Agriculturee</b></font></span>',
      stateName: 'remove-markers',
      onClick: function(control) {
        map.removeLayer(group);
        control.state('add-markers');
      },
      title: 'remove markers'
    }]
  }),
```

so im using map.addlayer, but it should more be something like map.addlayer(group.Transportationhub)

what function should a add to my code or how should a define each of the names in the group as individual layers?

"Group" is defined as:

```
var group = L.featureGroup(markerArray);
```

The icons are styled different based on the values in the spreedsheet:

```
  function determineLayers(points) {
    var layerNamesFromSpreadsheet = [];
    var layers = {};
    for (var i in points) {
      var pointLayerNameFromSpreadsheet = points[i].Group;
      if (layerNamesFromSpreadsheet.indexOf(pointLayerNameFromSpreadsheet) === -1) {
        markerColors.push(
          points[i]['Marker Icon'].indexOf('.') > 0
          ? points[i]['Marker Icon']
          : points[i]['Marker Color']
        );
        layerNamesFromSpreadsheet.push(pointLayerNameFromSpreadsheet);
      }
    }
```

Log.console(layerNamesFromSpreadsheet) : 
[image]

I have successfully used the easy buttons before with different filters based on the GeoJson, but this is different when the data is from spreedsheets.

Any simple funcktion a can use to seperate all the different names in the group?

Comment: After reading this, I'm not clear on where exactly you need help. Can you edit this question to indicate what exactly you need, and what is currently happening?

Comment: Hi, 
I need my buttons to turn on and off each layer in the gogle spreedsheet. The layers are grouped by the "group" column. So in the above a only want "group" to contain of transporttationhub. 
I asked another question that is related to my issue: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288256/filtering-points-based-on-attributes-in-leaflet